# antd Select Option not rendering when entering text in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, antd

I'm trying to implement a search box with remote data using `antd`'s `Select` and `Option`. I'm expecting that when I enter text into the search box, a list of options will be rendered immediately. Instead, the options only appear after when I clear the search box.

I have these states:

```
const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<React.ReactNode[]>();
```

and this component:

```
<Select
  showSearch
  value={symbol}
  onSearch={handleSearch}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  {searchResults}
</Select>
```

This is my handleSearch function:

```
const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
  if (value) {
    fetchStocksList(value, (data) => setSearchResults(data));
  }
};
```

This is the function used to fetch data from an api, the `console.log()` below can correctly log the data that I wanted:

```
const fetchStocksList = (
  value: string,
  callback: (data: React.ReactNode[]) => void
) => {
  axios
    .get(`${API_SERVER}/api/stocksinfo?search=${value}`)
    .then((res) => {
      let data: React.ReactNode[] = [];
      res.data.forEach((row: any) => {
        data.push(
          <Option value={row.symbol}>{row.symbol + ": " + row.name}</Option>
        );
      });
      return data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      callback(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};
```

May I ask why does the options not appear until after I clear the text that I entered in the search box?

Comment: can you put a `console.log` before the `if (value) {` in `handleSearch` function, and see if value is not empty while your writing in the box ?

Comment: @ggirodda thanks for the suggestion, but I just tried and the value is not empty when I type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out `filterOption={false}` needs to be added to the `Select` component, i.e. the following actually works:

```
<Select
  showSearch
  value={symbol}
  onSearch={handleSearch}
  onChange={handleChange}
  filterOption={false}
>
  {searchResults}
</Select>
```

The default value for `filterOption` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `optionFilterProp="children"` as `Select` component's props.